# ASP.Net / Javascript website: with IIS how to stop caching javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis-6

I have an update for my website and some Javascript files are changed. But some customers are still getting the old Javascript file and not the new one. They can remove their temporary internet files, but that's not what I want.

Is there something in IIS6 that I can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the link to the `.js` file - add a parameter `.js?ver=1.0`, for example.

Every time you change the `.js` file, change the parameter - this will ensure clients will be getting the latest version.

Comment: I've created a HttpModule which reads the complete HTML before it is send to the browser and add the .js?version=... to my js and css files. the value of the version= parameter is located in my web.config file. each time when I have an update I change this parameter, so my problem is solved !

Answer (score 1):

You can use "cache busting". A simple solution is to append a version number in the query string, eg: `script.js?v=1.1`.

Another solution is to dynamically calculate a checksum or hash of the .js file that gets automatically appended to the query string, so everytime you modify the contents of the .js file, a new checksum/hash is generated and appended to the query string.